# Android: How to send a push notification after a certain time of inactivity?

Tags: android, push-notification, user-inactivity

I want to send a push notification from my app if it was inactive (not used on this device) for a certain time of inactivity (for example one week).

I know how to send push notifications but I do not know how to add the time variable.

Hope you have some ideas!

Comment: Do you mean a local notification, or do you need to use actual push notifications?

Comment: A local notification would be sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possible solutions:
 1. Setup an alarm using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) every time the user exits your application and cancel it whenever your application starts.
 2. In case your application sends http requests to a server, or a server gets notified, in any way, when the user uses your app, detect the inactivity in the server side and send a cloud message when the app has been inactive for x amount of time.

Comment: Second one is better option. As first one keeps the processor busy.

Comment: I will setup a rasperry pi as server to realize this, because I also want to use Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you have two solution to implented : 
-local solution by using "service" runing in background in all the time which detect the local time (but this solution can consume your batterie) 
-extrenal solution = by push notification of GCM  (this solution depends the network connection )